# How to construct an class template with std::allocator construct

Tags: c++, allocator

How can i construct my class template in my member function newNode (in std=++98) without new operator ? 
I tried to put an constructor of Node or the variable key but it doesn't work .

```
template <class T>
class Node{
public:

    Node(){
        _left = NULL;
        _right = NULL;
        _height = 0;
    };

    Node(const Node &ref);
    Node &operator=(const Node &ref);
    ~Node(){};

    T _key;
    Node *_left;
    Node *_right;
    int _height;
};


template <class T, class A = std::allocator<Node<T> > >
class Tree{
public:
[...]
//attribut 
Node<T> *head;
A _alloc;


  Node<T> *newNode(T key){
    Node<T> *node = _alloc.allocate(sizeof(Node<T>));
    _alloc.construct(node, ???);

    return (node);
  }
};
```

What can i put in my 2nd argument of construct ?

Comment: The arguments to `Node`s constructor.

Comment: Judging by what little of this we see, I assume that argument is `key`.

Comment: node constructor doesn't work .
linker command failed: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../include/c++/10/ext/new_allocator.h:162: undefined reference to `Node<int>::Node(Node<int> const&)'

Comment: @EricLing can you present a [mcve] as required here please! What us `Node` where did you get it from?

Comment: @WhozCraig Nop you can't do this.

Comment: @EricLing Are you sure `Node` shouldn't have a constructor that initializes `_key` member?

Answer (score 1):

[`allocate()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/allocate) already calculates the memory required for objects, you shouldn't use `sizeof` there. Also, don't use [`construct()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/construct), it was removed in C++20. Use placement `new` instead:

```
  Node<T> *newNode(T key){
    Node<T> *node = _alloc.allocate(1); // allocate 1 * sizeof(Node<T>)
    new(node) Node<T>(/*arguments to Node<T> constructor, but Node<T> only has default constructor, so nothing goes here*/);

    return node;
  }
```

---

With C++20, you can also use [`std::construct_at()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/construct_at), which has easier syntax than placement `new`:

```
  Node<T> *newNode(T key){
    Node<T> *node = _alloc.allocate(1); // allocate 1 * sizeof(Node<T>)
    node = std::construct_at(node);

    return node;
  }
```

---

To use `construct()` before C++11, you need to create an object to be copied:

```
  Node<T> *newNode(T key){
    Node<T> *node = _alloc.allocate(1); // allocate 1 * sizeof(Node<T>)
    _alloc.construct(node, Node<T>());

    return node;
  }
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to tell this, I can't use new operator and have to use std c++98 for this exercice

Comment: @Myno This `new` is a placement new. It doesn't allocate memory, but it creates an object in the memory provided from somewhere else. `construct()` and `construct_at()` call placement new under the hood.